# QCompare test failure : wrong number of arguments produced by the [] operator on an unorded_map

Tags: c++, qt, qtestlib

Using c++/Qt5, I'm stuck with a QCOMPARE test on a MyMap object. This MyMap object has an attribute named "map" which is an unorded_map (vector < int,int> → QString).

Here is the test:

```
void TestMyMap::test(void)
{
  MyMap mymap = {
    { {{ {1,2}, {3,4} },}, QString("example1") },
    { {{ {1,2}, {3,5} },}, QString("example2") },
    { {{ {1,2}, {3,8} },}, QString("example3") },
  };

  QCOMPARE( mymap.size() , (std::size_t)3 );                   // OK
  QCOMPARE( mymap[{{ {1,2}, {3,8} }}] , QString("example3") ); // BOOM !
}
```

I got the following error on the last line : (my translation from the localized source message) :

```
error : the macro 'QCOMPARE' got 5 arguments but it takes only 2
```

I don't understand how *mymap[{{ {1,2}, {3,8} }}]* can somehow "produce" 4 arguments.

The MyMap operator[] is declared this way :

```
QString& operator[]( std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > key );  

QString& MyMap::operator[]( std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > key)
{
  return this->map[key];
}
```

The MyMap object is declared this way :

```
class MyMap {
    public:
        // PosRanges is a wrapper for vector < int, int >
        std::unordered_map<PosRanges, QString, PosRangesHasher> map;

    public:
        MyMap(std::initializer_list< IntegersAndAString >);
        QString& operator[]( std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > key );
        size_t  size(void);
};
```

Other tests on MyMap objects are ok. So, where's my error ?

Comment: Try `QCOMPARE( (mymap[...]) , QString("example3") )`

Comment: It works, thank you very much ! ... I just would like to know *why* I got this error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842468/comma-in-c-c-macro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro QCOMPARE is expecting two arguments separated by a comma. If an argument contains commas you have to put it into brackes ().

Hence:

```
QCOMPARE( ( mymap[{{ {1,2}, {3,8} }}] ) , QString("example3") )
          ^                           ^
```

You might read: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html