# macro MOCK_METHOD passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2 error with std::pair

Tags: c++, macros, std-pair, googlemock

I'm using Google Mock 1.6.0. When using the `MOCK_METHODN` macros, it seems to think I'm passing 3 arguments for methods that return a `std::pair`:

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <utility>
class IFoo {
public:
    virtual std::pair<int, int> bar() = 0;
};
class MockFoo {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(bar, std::pair<int, int>());
};
int main() {
    MockFoo f;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler output (GCC 4.6.3):

```
main.cpp:9:44: error: macro "MOCK_METHOD0" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
main.cpp:9:5: error: ‘MOCK_METHOD0’ does not name a type
```

This error doesn't appear if I:

- Replace `std::pair<int, int>` with a simple type like `int` or `void`
- Use on a method that has a `std::pair` argument, instead of returning it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with version 1.6.0. The same code works with **version 1.7.0**, so the best solution would be to **upgrade to that**.

Alternately, compiling with Clang also runs into the same error, but provides a strong clue where the error is:

```
main.cpp:9:38: error: too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
    MOCK_METHOD0(bar, std::pair<int, int>());
                                     ^
main.cpp:9:5: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
    MOCK_METHOD0(bar, std::pair<int, int>());
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
```

Looks like a buggy macro expansion is interpreting the `,` inside `std::pair<int, int>` as another argument. Therefore, you can also work around the issue by avoiding the `,`, for instance using a `typedef`:

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> MyType;
class MockFoo {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(bar, MyType());
};
```

Comment: If upgrading to 1.7.0 isn't an option, here's a question with a number of workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842468/comma-in-c-c-macro.

Answer (score 2):

In [FAQ GoogleMock](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions):

> You still need a typedef if the return type contains an unprotected comma, but that's much rarer.

Use typedef