# C macros with new lines in generated code

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, macros

I need macro which expands into multiple lines of code. For example:

```
#define foo(...)
foo(something, something_else, ...)
...
```

Should be converted into:

```
something
something_else
...
```

And not into:

```
something something_else ...
```

---

Also if you wonder why I need such thing. I need to generate such code, new line is part of inline assembly syntax.

```
_asm
{
    mov eax, 3
    div 5
}
```

---

I'm interested in any form of achieving this, so all suggestions are welcome.

Just an idea after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19841470/1237747). Would it be possible to have a macro for new line and call `foo(something, NL, something_else, NL, ...)`?

---

I'm also more interested into variadic version but knowing simpler version may also help.

Comment: You cannot. This doesn't even make sense, as there are no longer any lines after preprocessing. There is only an unbroken stream of tokens.

Comment: You *can* nest _asm statements and/or give each instruction its own _asm prefix. You don't need newlines in this case.

Comment: Depending how your code generation works exactly, you could also get away with just `#include`ing different snippets of code which make use of variables you define prior to `#include`ing.

Comment: @n.m. Have been thinking about that. However instruction may have or may not have comma, so that annoys me.

Comment: I have to ask why?  What does it achieve to put your assembly language instructions in a macro?

Comment: The compiler used here might be relevant. With `gcc`, inline assembly in a single line wouldn't be an issue...

Comment: @JeremyP It is long story. In short it saves time.

Comment: @FelixPalmen however VS-2012 is used.

Comment: @ST3 how does writing `foo( .... )` save time over writing `_asm { ... }`? The answer is important because, depending on what it is, I might have a solution for you that isn't what you asked for exactly but will do the job.

Comment: @ST3 look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/352sth8z.aspx -- the syntax looks a bit silly, but from how I read it, you get your `__asm` block all in one line by prefixing each single instruction with `__asm`

Comment: You may be able to use this http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27875b7bbe4cc6aa

Comment: @n.m. Good suggestion, it is slightly more typing but works. Thanks! You can add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This may provide a little bit of help , to just give you an idea

```
    #include "stdio.h"
    #define EXPAND_MULTIPLE_LINES(X, Y, Z) /*
    */ X /*
    */ Y /*
    */ Z

    int main()
    {
        int X, Y, Z;
        EXPAND_MULTIPLE_LINES(X, Y, Z);
        return 0;
    }
```

use gcc -E -CC testMacro.c

Output like

```
     # 844 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4

     # 2 "testMacro.c" 2
     # 12 "testMacro.c"
     int main()

     {

          int X, Y, Z;
          /*

          */ X /*
          */ Y /*
          */ Z;
          # 18 "testMacro.c"
          return 0;
     }
```