# BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT with two template parameters

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion

Here is a coliru of the error:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a03c61dc0c33c94b

I have a type with two template parameters like so:

```
template <typename T, typename U> class DoubleTemplate {};
```

In a struct I have a member of the above type like so:

```
namespace test
{
    struct adaptee
    {
        DoubleTemplate<int, int> dt;
    };
}
```

When I attempt to call the Boost adapt function like so:

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT( test::adaptee,
    (DoubleTemplate<int, int>, dt) )
```

it complains that there are 3 parameters being passed in (I am guessing it is seeing these three: `DoubleTemplate<int`, `int>`, `dt`)

It works ok if I `typedef` the `DoubleTemplate` type and use the shorter name in the Boost adapt call, but that would require a nasty 10-or-so `typedef`s in my code.

Is there a simple way to just pass in the double template? I feel like I am missing a simple answer here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but if you are using boost 1.58 or higher you can simply use [`BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT( test::adaptee, dt )`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4be39a0cd86a182a).

Comment: I cannot comment, so I'm posting it as an answer. See answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842468/comma-in-c-c-macro). **upd**: It turns out that short answers become comments even if you don't have enough reputation.