# Attribute propagation rule for repeat (%)

Tags: c++, boost, attributes, boost-spirit

I have checked this webpage http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/compound_attribute_rules.html, and many others, but couldn't find an answer to my question.

I have a rule of the form C %= A % B, where B is a parser and NOT a literal, and it is of different type than A. The rule given on the webpage above says:

```
a: A, b: B --> (a % b): vector<A>
```

but given that in my case B is a parser and not of type A this rule doesn't seem to do the trick.

I have tried out this:

```
(a % b): variant<A, tuple<B,A>>
```

and as a consequence defined this structure:

```
    struct equality_expression
    {
        variant<A,tuple<B,A>> equexp;
    };
```

and thereafter

```
    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
        equality_expression,
        (variant<A,tuple<B,A>>, equexp);
    )
```

but the compiler complains:

```
warning C4002: too many actual parameters for macro 'BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT_FILLER_0'
```

So, what's the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

The way to read `a: A, b: B --> (a % b): vector<A>` is: "if parser `a` exposes an attribute `A` and parser `b` exposes an attribute `B` then `a%b` exposes the attribute `vector<A>`", meaning that the attribute of B is always ignored in the list parser. The problem with your macro invocation are [the commas that separate the template parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32105267/boost-fusion-adapt-struct-with-two-template-parameters).

Comment: OK, good to know about B being ignored, thanks. Lets take a step back: I have a grammar rules like this: C ::= A | (B >> A), and C ::= qi::eps |  A; What attributes are exposed by these rules?

Comment: [`variant<A,tuple<B,A> >` and `optional<A>`](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/alternative.html#spirit.qi.reference.operator.alternative.attributes).