# How long does a typedef last for?

Tags: c++

I have a macro in a function that instantiates a variable of a given type (and does a couple of other things that are not relevant).

Essentially `MACRO(foo, f)` expands to `foo f;`

But if `foo` is say a `std::map<int, int>` then the expansion fails due to the extra comma.

I work around this by writing `typedef std::map<int, int> bar;` followed by `MACRO(bar, b)`.

I'm concerned though that I'm leaking `typedef`s into the program source which may cause me problems in the future.

So, how long do `typedef`s last for?

Comment: You may find some use in reading about [The XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Wait, so you are saying that `typedef std::map<int, int> foo; MACRO(foo, f)` does not compile? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: btw "(and does a couple of other things that are not relevant)" is a quite common misconception. There is nothing irrelevant if it is related to the question. If your question involves a macro, then show us the macro (or a distilled version that shows same behavior with respect to the question), but please do not claim that it is not relevant.

Comment: No that does compile but MACRO(std::map<int, int>, f) doesn't

Comment: Maybe you want to check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842468/comma-in-c-c-macro

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rules for `typedef` availability are identical to those for a variable so in your case it will "last" as long as the function body.

You could have verified this yourself by writing

`{typedef std::map<std::string, std::string, iLT> location_map;}`

and observing the compiler errors: as soon as the scope block exists, the `typedef` itself is out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

`typedef` lasts until end of translation unit in global scope or namespace scope.

or end of scope when put inside an other scope.