# How to evaluate comma in a #define

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, pic, xc8

I'm using XC8 compiler to develop a small embedded application with a PIC. In XC8 to set the usage of a pin (output or input), the programmer should perform an instruction like this:

```
TRISAbits.RA0 = 1;
```

in particular:

- TRIS in the prefix of the register (constant)
- A is the port
- bits is the suffix (constant)
- RA0 is the name of the pin

What I want to do is to define all pins with a human-readable name, like:

```
#define LED_1     A,RA0
#define LED_2     A,RA1
#define SWITCH_1  B,RB5
...
```

And define some macros like `SET_OUTPUT` or `SET_INPUT` used in this way: `SET_OUTPUT(LED_1)`.

What I tried to do is these two macros:

```
#define SET_INPUT(port, pin)  TRIS ## port ## bits. ## pin ## = 0
```

however, the comma inside the previously defined constants is not expanded and interpreted as a single argument. I tried also:

```
#define SET_INPUT(X)  SET_INPUT_(X ## "")
#define SET_INPUT_(port, pin)  TRIS ## port ## bits. ## pin ## = 0
```

without success.

Essentially is the opposite of this question: [Comma in C/C++ macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842468/comma-in-c-c-macro)

Does it exist a solution or a more convenient way to do that?

Comment: At the start you say it should be `= 1`, but then you tried `= 0` in your macros, what's that about?

Answer (score 3):

You were close:

```
#define SET_INPUT(X)  SET_INPUT_(X)
#define SET_INPUT_(port, pin)  TRIS ## port ## bits.pin = 1
```

The `##` is only for pasting two tokens to form another token.  For cases where you are not forming a new token (e.g. `bits.pin`) you don't need to do anything special.

I would recommend [statement-izing the macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-use-apparently-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros):

```
#define SET_INPUT_(port, pin)  do { TRIS ## port ## bits.pin = 1; } while (0)
```