# Dealing with extra parentheses in macros in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros

There are some cases where you need to (a) have a macro which (b) parenthesizes one of its arguments in (c) a case where the language does not allow parentheses.

Simple example:

```
#define MAKE_STRUCT(name, base) struct name : base { }

struct X { };
MAKE_STRUCT(Y, X);   // ok
MAKE_STRUCT(Z, (X)); // error
```

This is an error because we're expecting a type name and we get `(`. [ecatmur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13842784/2069064) provides a clever workaround for this by taking advantage of the fact that there are *other* parts of the language that do allow for an extra set of parentheses:

```
template<typename T> struct argument_type;
template<typename T, typename U> struct argument_type<T(U)> { typedef U type; };

#define MAKE_STRUCT(name, base) struct name : argument_type<void(base)>::type { }

struct X { };
MAKE_STRUCT(Y, X);   // ok
MAKE_STRUCT(Z, (X)); // ok
```

This compiles on gcc and clang, but it does not compile on MSVC. Is there either an MSVC-specific trick to allow for parentheses or a different trick that works on all three compilers?

This possibly-parenthesized type is passed through several macros - so I'm not sure that the other answers could apply (the context here is trying to pass multiple template parameters to a fixture using Catch2's `TEST_CASE_METHOD()`).

Comment: @VTT Nope. No such luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I came to the following pure-preprocessor solution that will strip parentheses only when they are present. Seems to work in vc++, g++ and clang++ and probably can be modified to deal with several levels of parentheses.

```
#define MAKE_STRUCT(name, base) struct name: EXPAND1(DEF base) {}
#define EXPAND1(param) EXPAND2(param)
#define EXPAND2(param) NO## param
#define DEF(param) DEF param
#define NODEF

struct X { };
MAKE_STRUCT(Y, X);   // ok
MAKE_STRUCT(Z, (X)); // ok
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/g/iik2VN)

Comment: In my case the `X` really has a comma in it, but that's a trivial change to make `DEF` and `EXPAND2` take `...` instead. Wonderful, thank you. The preprocessor is still basically magic to me.

Answer (score -1):

Not the great solution, but if structs in question can be tinkered with, and only ONE level of parenthesis is to be supported, this seems to work:

```
struct tag {};

#define MAKE_STRUCT(name, base) struct name : \
  decltype(base(tag{})) { };

struct X {
     X(tag );
     X() = default;
};

MAKE_STRUCT(Y, X);   // ok
MAKE_STRUCT(Z, (X)); // ok
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But I'm fascinated that this works whereas, like, `base()` doesn't?