# Passing function parameters to a function through a macro

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I want to create a macro in which one of the parameters is the parameters for a function used within the macro.

```
#define Macro(PERAMS, OTHER) \
    functionBeingUsed(PERAMS); \
    OTHER; 


Macro(1,2,3,4, int i = 0);
```

As you can see you can see the commas are being used by both the macro and the function. which results in broken code.

I was wondering if there was a way to achieve the result that I need so the code can be interpreted like the following.

```
Macro((1,2,3,4), int i = 0);
```

Please note I am not using C++11.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13842468/2602718

Comment: You should try to avoid using macros… What are you trying to achieve. I don't see from the example above what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you need to do anything nontrivial with the preprocessor, you should *immediately* jump to the Boost.PP library. Here, the [BOOST_PP_REMOVE_PARENS](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/remove_parens.html) macro seems relevant:

```
#define Macro(PARAMS, OTHER) \
    functionBeingUsed(BOOST_PP_REMOVE_PARENS(PARAMS)); \
    OTHER; 

Macro((1,2,3,4), int i = 0);
```

Alternatively, you could just write `functionBeingUsed PARAMS` and let the passed parentheses be used.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do what you have described.  However, you can do something similar with [variadic macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177415.aspx).  You would need to put the PARAMS part at the end and it would look like the following:

```
#define Macro(OTHER, ...) \
    functionBeingUsed(__VA_ARGS__); \
    OTHER;

Macro(int i = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: Sorry that i did not say this but I am not using c++ 11.

Comment: This is why variadic macros were added, because it wasn't possible before.

Comment: Variadic macros were also part of C99, which technically isn't necessarily part of C++, but many compilers support the above syntax even without being in C++11 mode.

Comment: It is possible, see my answer.

Comment: @o11c: You change the call syntax though. Mine uses OP syntax (and supports it  up to hard coded value).

Comment: @Jarod42 changing the order is a bigger deal ... actually, by dispatching based on the number of arguments, I suppose it *is* technically possible to preserve the exact syntax ...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only answer is to use multiple macros

```
#define MacroBegin \
   \\PreFunction

#define MacroEnd \
   \\PostFunction

MacroBegin
functionBeingCalled(1,2,3,4);
MacroEnd
```

Comment: And how does this address the OP's issue exactly?

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's a common and useful technique, especially with longer bodies, since it doesn't mess up line numbers during macro expansion. Though using an "x-macros" .def header may be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

To differentiate which commas belong to the macro itself and which belong to the function being called, you have to wrap the function parameters in parenthesis, eg:

```
Macro((1,2,3,4), int i = 0);
```

You would then have to remove the parenthesis from the function call inside the macro, since they will be coming from the macro parameter instead, eg:

```
#define Macro(PERAMS, OTHER) \
    functionBeingUsed PERAMS; \
    OTHER;
```

So, something like this:

```
Macro((1,2,3,4), int i = 0);
```

Will resolve to this:

```
functionBeingUsed (1,2,3,4);
int i = 0;
```

Just remember the extra parenthesis even if the function being called doesn't take any input parameters:

```
Macro((), ...);
```

```
functionBeingUsed ();
...;
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep your syntax, you may do something like:

```
#define COUNT_N(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, N, ...)    N
#define COUNT(...)   COUNT_N(__VA_ARGS__, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
// Warning: COUNT() return 1 (as COUNT(A)) :-/

#define IDENTITY(N) N
#define APPLY(macro, ...) IDENTITY(macro(__VA_ARGS__))

#define F_1(a) functionBeingUsed(); a;
#define F_2(a, b) functionBeingUsed(a); b;
#define F_3(a, b, c) functionBeingUsed(a, b); c;
#define F_4(a, b, c, d) functionBeingUsed(a, b, c); d;
#define F_5(a, b, c, d, e) functionBeingUsed(a, b, c, d); e;
#define F_6(a, b, c, d, e, f) functionBeingUsed(a, b, c, d, e); f;
#define F_7(a, b, c, d, e, f, g) functionBeingUsed(a, b, c, d, e, f); g;
#define F_8(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h) functionBeingUsed(a, b, c, d, e, f, g); h;

#define DISPATCH(N) F_ ## N

#define Macro(...) IDENTITY(APPLY(DISPATCH, COUNT(__VA_ARGS__)))(__VA_ARGS__)
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/EffpBz)

but simpler to change your syntax to:

```
#define Macro(PARAMS, OTHER)  \
    functionBeingUsed PARAMS; \
    OTHER;

Macro((1,2,3,4), int i = 0);
```