# Macro htonl interpretes inner commas as parameter separator

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, htonl

This is a unusual error returned at compile time, only with some compiler parameters.

OK with `g++ -std=c++11 -m64 -O3 -DNDEBUG`

But with `g++ -std=c++11 -m64 -Wall -g`, this problem occurs:

> macro "htonl" passed 7 arguments, but takes just 1

Code:

```
const unsigned int h = htonl(hash::CompileTime<'A', 'S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g'>::hash);
```

I'm not sure if the problem comes from the call of `htonl`or if it comes from my templated hasher.

Do you know how to solve that?

Other infos:

```
template<const char C0,         const char C1 =  '\0', const char C2 =  '\0', 
         const char C3  = '\0', const char C4 =  '\0', const char C5 =  '\0', 
         const char C6  = '\0', const char C7 =  '\0', const char C8 =  '\0', 
         const char C9  = '\0', const char C10 = '\0'>
struct CompileTime
{
    //Do you think this code could help?
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add another pair of braces:

`htonl((hash::CompileTime<'A', 'S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g'>::hash))`

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to help the macro with additional parenthesis:

```
const unsigned int h = htonl((hash::CompileTime<'A', 'S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g'>::hash));
```

To explain why... this post will help
[Comma in C/C++ macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842468/comma-in-c-c-macro)

It's a question of comma interpretation inside macros.