# Macro with an actionBlock causes compiler errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macros, completionhandler

I have defined a set of macros to visually simplify my code when creating `UIActionController` and `UIAlertAction` statements.  The macros work fine, but there is one situation that causes compiler errors.  Although there is a simple workaround, I'm trying to understand why these errors occur and how to rewrite the macro to eliminate the need for the workaround.

There are two macros defined, below.  The **first** macro is included only to allow the example code to compile.

My issue concerns the **second** macro.  It has two arguments.  One is a string and the other is an `actionBlock` (for a `completionHandler`).  If the `actionBlock` contains a statement with an array or a method call with multiple arguments (that resemble an array), the compiler complains.  The errors can be eliminated by adding a pair of parentheses, as shown.

```
- (void)macroTest
{
#define ALERT_CREATE( title, msg )  \
    UIAlertController *alertController = \
        [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title \
        message:msg preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert]

#define ALERT_DEFAULT_ACTION( title, actionBlock ) \
    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:title \
        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault \
        handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) { actionBlock } ]]

    // Example code
    ALERT_CREATE( @"Alert Title", @"Alert Message" );

    // This example is fine (no errors):
    ALERT_DEFAULT_ACTION( @"Action 1 Title" , /* actionBlock */
                         int i = 1;
                         i++;
                         );

    // This results in error: Use of undeclared identifier 'ALERT_DEFAULT_ACTION'
    ALERT_DEFAULT_ACTION( @"Action 2a Title" ,
                         // Another error: Too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
                         NSArray *test = @[ @"1", @"2" ]; // not okay
                         );

    ALERT_DEFAULT_ACTION( @"Action 2b Title" ,
                         // The same code as 2a, but with parens, is okay
                         NSArray *test = (@[ @"1", @"2" ]); // this is okay (with parens)
                         );

    ALERT_DEFAULT_ACTION( @"Action 3 Title" ,
                         // Parentheses are needed here, too, to avoid error
                         NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"format %@", @"arg")];                                   NSString *str2 = ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"format %@", @"arg"]);
                         );

    `enter code here`// The next line displays the alert.  It's commented out to avoid errors in this example.
    // [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Why does the compiler complain and how can I rewrite the second macro so I don't have to add the parentheses to some of the statements in its actionBlock?  I'm using Xcode 11.3.

UPDATE:
It also confuses Xcode's indentation logic if there's a conditional in the actionBlock.  To wit:

```
ALERT_DEFAULT_ACTION( @"Action 4a Title" ,
                     // code here, correct indentation
                     );
ALERT_DEFAULT_ACTION( @"Action 4b Title" ,
                     if ( true ) {
    // code here, incorrect indentation
} // incorrect indenation
                     );
```

Comment: Ok, I'll be trivial - don't use macro, it is XXI outdoor. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question  should have been marked as a duplicate because there are several similar questions with answers.  The trick is using good search terms (hint, search for: passing a block in a macro).

The solution is to use **variadic** functions ("..." and **VA_ARGS**).  The last argument to the macro gobbles up everything in the block, including commas, as explained in this excellent article: Sending blocks as arguments to macros
https://mort.coffee/home/obscure-c-features/

In case that link becomes orphaned, here's the important point:

> The pre-processor supports **variadic** macros; macros which can take an
>   unlimited amount of arguments. The way they are implemented is that
>   any extra arguments (indicated by ... in the macro definition) are
>   made available through the **VA_ARGS** identifier; **VA_ARGS** is
>   replaced with all the extra arguments separated by commas. [This
>   passes] a block of code, with unguarded commas, to a macro.

That post gives credit to this early solution from 2012:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13842612/1578823 So, +1 there.

Here's my fixed macro:

```
#define ALERT_DEFAULT_ACTION( title, ... /* actionBlock */ ) \
    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:title \
        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault \
        handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) { {__VA_ARGS__} /* actionBlock */ }]]
```

This does not solve the issue of incorrectly indented brackets (e.g., in if-statements).  That's just too confusing for Xcode.

```
ALERT_DEFAULT_ACTION( @"title",
                     NSArray *test = @[ @"1", @"2" ]; // commas okay now
                     if ( true ) {
    test = test; // incorrect indentation
} // incorrect indentation
                     test = test;
                     );
```